# Richfaces 3.3.2 - JSF 1.2 - Facelets in RAD 7.5 and IBM WAS 7.0

Tags: jsf, websphere, richfaces, facelets, ibm-rad

I'd like to know which is the best way to use JBoss richFaces (3.3.2) with SUN RI jsf implementation (1.2) under RAD 7.5 and WAS 7.0, with facelets. We inverted class loader policy at the application level to obtain this, but I'm not sure this is the best way to do it (parent last policy could be potentially harmful).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

IBM Webshere ships with builtin JSF libraries which may indeed be of an older version than the libraries you ship with your webapp. Easiest way is indeed to let the webapp ship with newer libraries and change the classloading policy to avoid collisions with the older builtin JSF libraries. This may only be harmful if you're overridding IBM/webshere specific libraries (the ones of `com.ibm` package and so on).

Other solution is to upgrade Websphere with newer libraries as per IBM Websphere upgrade service/instructions.